# Doubles consonnes

Tags: orthographe, rule-of-thumb

Y a-t-il des règles ou des moyens mnémotechniques pour savoir quels mots s'orthographient avec des doubles consonnes quand cela n'affecte pas la prononciation ?

Comment: Vous avez des exemples?

Comment: Au hasard : parallèle, appeler, aller, grolle, différence.

Comment: Je crois qu'il n'y a pas de règle. Les prononciations des formes *appeler* et *j'appelle* sont différentes (*é* et *è*); cela peut aider.

Comment: Je pensais au double *p*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En ce qui concerne la gémination du 'l', je dirais qu'il y a souvent une différence de prononciation (accentuée dans certains accents régionaux) qui aide à deviner.

Plusieurs décennies de cassage de dents sur les 't' et les 'p' (avec lesquels j'ai toujours du mal à ce jour) me poussent à dire que non: les quelques règles qui existent, sont contrebalancées par autant d'exceptions, et presque tout les moyens "mnémotechniques" sont du cas-par-cas et pas particulièrement brillants ("j'aperçois un 'p' à apercevoir").

Une des seules choses qui ait pu m'aider par le passé (et qui fut une mini-épiphanie le jour où on me l'a apprise) est qu'il n'existe pas de mots préfixés par 're' (au sens de 'seconde fois', comme dans 'relire' ou 'repartir') qui soient immédiatement suivis d'un doublement de consonne (aucun exemple ne me vient en tête, mais il m'arrivait d'hésiter sur certains mots avant de connaître cette "règle").

J'ajouterais que la connaissance de l'orthographe anglaise des mots correspondants est souvent un handicap (*literature* vs. littérature, *dictionary* vs dictionnaire etc.), mais la connaissance de la racine latine peut parfois aider: le double 'p' provient souvent d'une assimilation régressive [? ma philologie est un peu rouillée] de préfixes tel que 'ad' ou 'ab' en latin (d'où 'aPercevoir', mais 'aPPrendre' ou 'aPPorter')...

Comment: Il y en a quelques-uns en `ress-`: ressaisir, ressentir, ressortir, ... Mais ressusciter (prononcé [res-]), resucer (prononcé [rəs-]).

Comment: @Gilles: arf. Il suffit de trouver une règle de grammaire française, pour trouver trois (ou mille) exceptions. Il semblerait néanmoins que ces exemples soient tous liés à 's', dont le doublement est en général facile à identifier.

Comment: Comme on dit, c'est l'exception qui confirme la règle. Dans la liste de mots de mon correcteur orthographique, les seuls mots qui commencent par `re-` suivi d'une consonne double sont *reddition* (`[rεd-]`) et  *renne* (`[rεn]`) qui ne sont pas construits sur ce préfixe (enfin, *reddition* l'est, mais il vient directement du latin avec deux `d`) et *remmailler* (`[ʀɑ̃m-]`) et *remmancher* (`[ʀɑ̃m-]`) (plus bien sûr les mots de la même famille) qui ont le préfixe « r- » suivi de « em- ».